# IIS / PHPMailer authentication problems on live server but works on localhost

Tags: php, iis, phpmailer

I'm able to send emails through my external SMTP server (livemail), but only on localhost. Attempting the exact same code on my web server (Windows server, running IIS) gives me:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Here's the code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.livemail.co.uk');
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'USERNAME';
$mail->Password = 'PASSWORD';
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->SetFrom('EMAIL');
$mail->Subject = 'SUBJECT';
$mail->msgHTML('MESSAGE');
$mail->AddAddress("EMAIL");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $msg_sent = true;
}
```

What I've checked:

- SMTP service is installed & running on my IIS server
- Ports 25, 465, 587 are allowed in firewall outbound & inbound

I've attempted to send emails on my IIS server via my Gmail account with Allow less secure apps ON, **with success.**

So as far as I can tell the problem is not:

- my set up of PHPMailer (as it works using Gmail on live)
- firewall (I've tested using `tnc smtp.livemail.co.uk -port 465` on Power Shell there is a response)

I'm running out of ideas and would greatly appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

The complete error log for TLS:587 is:

```
2020-05-01 11:43:00 Connection: opening to smtp.livemail.co.uk:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-05-01 11:43:00 Connection: opened
2020-05-01 11:43:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.livemail.co.uk ESMTP Postfix
2020-05-01 11:43:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO (domain)
2020-05-01 11:43:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.livemail.co.uk250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 153600000250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
2020-05-01 11:43:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-05-01 11:43:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2020-05-01 11:43:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO (domain)
2020-05-01 11:43:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.livemail.co.uk250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 153600000250-VRFY250-ETRN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2020-05-01 11:43:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-05-01 11:43:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
2020-05-01 11:43:03 Connection: closed
```

Comment: Why do you use `gethostbyname`? And what have you tried further to debug the problem? A dedicated SMTP service on your own server should not be needed, as you send your mail using another server

Comment: @NicoHaase I wasn't sure if the problem was with IPv6, but I have tried with and without it

Comment: Using `gethostbyname` means that you can't use TLS, as you're no longer connecting to a hostname but a literal IP address, and thus certificate verification will fail. You're turning off verification (presumably that reason), but doing that is a *symptom*, not a solution. Since you have a local mail server, sending through that is actually preferable - it will be faster and more reliable - and will avoid most of these issues.

Comment: @Synchro Thanks for the info - I didn't know that! Just tried removing `gethostbyname` and setting to TLS:587, same authentication error unfortunately

Comment: Can you show the complete transcript?

Comment: The obvious problem there is that this server does not appear to support authentication! Notice that `AUTH` does not appear in the list of server capabilities. I don't know why that would be, but it doesn't look like the problem is at your end. I suggest you ask their support service.